What is the formula for microwave time?
If it takes one minute to heat one cup of milk, how long would it take to heat 2, 3, 4 identical cups together in the same microwave?
Let's assume the cups sit on a rotating table.
Is there a formula?

How do you define “heat one cup of milk”? Even with the rotating table microwave energy is not uniformly distributed in the oven cavity. Temperatures will vary among the cups of milk. Probably the best you can say is the total available energy is distributed in some manner among the cups of milk.

I just wanted to fix the quantity of milk in a cup so that it is the same for each cup.

Probably a question for Cooking Stack Exchange, or even better, Trial and Error as machines are different.  Physics Stack can discuss physical principles, but most physical systems in real life, particularly involving heating and cooling, are too complex to be described by a simple formula

I believe an experiment is needed. Liquids do not work like solids or mixtures as in some other posts.

What matters is the power delivered by the microwave.  For constant power and $n$ identical cups containing the same amount of liquid, should it not take roughly $n$ times as long?
It depends somewhat on exactly where the cups are, but why not just do the experiment?

Hard to say precisely. If the oven was perfect at delivering energy to the food being heated, heating two things would take twice as  long, three things three times as long, etc. This is often a tolerable approximation.
However, microwave ovens reflect some of the microwave energy back to its source, a magnetron. That heats up the magnetron rather than the food. How much gets reflected depends on what the food is, how much there is, and how it's arranged in the oven.

The food in this case is milk
